# How to asynchronously import components in VueJS by full URL

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, webpack-2

I need to import a Vue component asynchronously by the full URL opposed to relative URL.  The following example taken from the [VueJS documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Async-Components) works just fine for components within the same project

```
Vue.component(
  'app-component-one',
  () => import('./component-from-app-one')
)
```

However, my goal is to import components from a separate project that's deployed on the same server.  I was hoping I could use the full URL and do something like...

```
Vue.component(
  'app-component-two',
   () => import ('http://sample-domain.com/project-2/components/component-from-app-two.vue')
)
```

but it results in and error:

```
This dependency was not found:
* http://sample-domain.com/app-2/components/component-from-app-two.vue in ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0&bustCache!./src/components/SampleComponent.vue
```

Is importing components by full URL possible?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Shouldn't `http:sample-domain.com` be `http://sample-domain.com`?

Comment: @AsaStallard yep you are right.  I fixed this in my question above. thx

Comment: if you want to asynchronously import components you can use lazy-loading feature in vue-router. in your question you mentioned as if you need to access using a different URL. In that case you need to have two separate vuejs build files to make this work.

Answer (score 1):

The example you referenced from the Vue website is leveraging the [code-splitting functionality from WebPack](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/), so it will NOT work to load files that are not part of the same project.

What you are trying to do is typically called "dynamic/asynchronous ES6 module loading". Not to get too deep in to it.. but the current `import blah from X` only support static imports. If you care more about the nitty-gritty details of this.. there is a [TC39 proposal for dynamic imports in JS](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-dynamic-import)

In the mean time... us mortals have to depend on tools like [SystemJS](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs) which will do exactly what you are asking for.

But like @divine mentioned... you need some type of build-process that generates the stand-alone Vue component. You can use either WebPack or RollUp to export it as a UMD and the use SystemJS to import that component by referencing the full URL (you could even import it from a different domain! assuming that domain supports CORS)

Comment: Maurice, webpack now supports import() could you update your answer?

Comment: @ydennis - good call. I'll do a test some time this week to make sure that the new webpack `import()` function works cross-domain.